# limsup of a sequence of random variables (definition)

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, limsup-and-liminf

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of random variables.

First, $\limsup X_n=\inf_n\{\sup_{m\ge n}X_m\}$. So,

$$\{\limsup X_n\le c\}=\bigcup_n\bigcap_{m\ge n}\{X_m\le c\}$$

Is it correct to say that if $P\{X_n\le c \text{   i.o.}\}\equiv P\{\limsup\{X_n\le c\}\}=1$ then $\limsup X_n\le c \text{ a.s.}$?

**Edit 1:**

By the same way

$$\{\liminf X_n\ge c\}=\bigcup_n\bigcap_{m\ge n}\{X_m\ge c\}$$

So, $P\{X_n\ge c \text{   i.o.}\}=1 \Rightarrow \liminf X_n\ge c \text{ a.s.}$

**Edit 2:**

Following @Did's comments, the answer follows from

$$[X_n\geqslant c\ \text{i.o.}]\subseteq[\limsup X_n\geqslant c] \text { and } [X_n\leqslant c\ \text{i.o.}]\subseteq[\liminf X_n\leqslant c]$$

Comment: your question needs repairs.

Comment: @drhab pls explain...

Comment: $P\left\{ X_{n}\geq c\: i.o\right\} \Rightarrow$... How can a value on its own imply something?

Comment: Copy-paste typo ...

Comment: The third line is wrong. In general, $$\{\limsup X_n\le c\}\ne\bigcup_n\bigcap_{m\ge n}\{X_m\le c\}=\liminf\{X_n\le c\}.$$ (I corrected the typo $X_n$ for $X_m$.) It is not even always true that $$\{\limsup X_n\le c\}=\limsup\{X_n\le c\}.$$
For example, if $X_n(\omega)=c+1/n$ for every $n$, then $\limsup X_n(\omega)=\lim X_n(\omega)=c$ hence $\omega$ is in the event $\{\limsup X_n\le c\}$ but $X_n(\omega)\gt c$ for every $n$ hence $\omega$ is neither in the event $\limsup\{X_n\le c\}$ nor in the event $\liminf\{X_n\le c\}$.

Comment: Exercise: Disprove the identity $$\{\liminf X_n\ge c\}=\bigcup_n\bigcap_{m\ge n}\{X_m\ge c\}(=\liminf \{X_n\ge c\}).$$

Comment: Thank's. I got it. However, what can we say about $\limsup X_n$, $\liminf X_n$ if we know that $P\{X_n \ge c \text{ i.o.} \}=1$ or $P\{X_n \le c \text{ i.o.} \}=1$?

Comment: $[X_n\geqslant c\ \text{i.o.}]\subseteq[\limsup X_n\geqslant c]$ and $[X_n\leqslant c\ \text{i.o.}]\subseteq[\liminf X_n\leqslant c]$ $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Let $X_{n}=\left(-1\right)^{n}$ (constant random variables) so that: $$P\left\{ X_{n}\leq0\text{ i.o.}\right\} =1=P\left\{ X_{n}\geq0\text{ i.o.}\right\}$$

However $\limsup X_{n}=1$ and $\liminf X_{n}=-1$ so that: $$P\left\{ \limsup X_{n}\leq0\right\} =0=P\left\{ \liminf X_{n}\geq0\right\}$$

---

**addendum**:

Let $\left(a_{n}\right)$ be some sequence in $\mathbb{R}$.

Then:
$$\limsup a_{n}>c\implies a_{n}>c\text{ i.o.}\implies\limsup a_n\geq c$$

Comment: I think you made a mistake in the addendum. We have $1/n >0$ infinitely often, yet $\limsup 1/n = 0$.

Comment: @rabota You are correct. Thank you for attending me. I repaired.